# Why is my counter not working?

Tags: php, bash, shell

I have a bash script that is intended to run a PHP script every 15 seconds, and a second PHP script every 5 minutes. However, my counter to do so is not working. I can't find where the bug is.

```
#!/bin/bash

while (true)
do
    sleep 1
    if (( count % 15 == 0 )) ;then
            php test.php
    fi
    if (( count % 300 == 0 )); then
            php test2.php
            count=0
    fi

     (( count = count +1 ))


done
```

When I run this script, it gives me this error in the console:

```
script.sh: 8: script.sh: count: not found
script.sh: 11: script.sh: count: not found
script.sh: 16: script.sh: count: not found
script.sh: 8: script.sh: count: not found
script.sh: 11: script.sh: count: not found
script.sh: 16: script.sh: count: not found
```

I have tried to instantiate the counter prior to the loop, but it ends with the same result. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: while(true) ???. Anyways, you did not define count so it cant work here. Your working with a variable which does not exist.

Comment: count is not defined :P

Comment: Hint: Use `watch -n15 php test.php` and `watch -n5 php test2.php` to achieve this.

Comment: I was under the impression that declaring the counter the first time would instantiate it at 0. The loop is intended to run forever, hence why it's `while(true)`. I'll update the OP with the result when I instantiate the counter prior to the loop.

Comment: count does not need to be defined, variables are set to 0 on there first occurence

Comment: Just figured it out. Thanks @Jidder for writing the script and trying to help me figure out what I was doing wrong! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad you sorted it :). What was the problem ?

Comment: @Jidder I was executing the script using `sh` haha fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably execute the script with `sh` instead of `bash`. Make sure you execute it directy with `./script.sh` (so that the shebang binary is used) or call it explicitly with bash `bash script.sh`

Comment: ... I am most definitely using sh to run the script... that is properly 100% the reason. I'll check right now and edit this comment... facepalm **EDIT** - Yup, that's it. That's really dumb of me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to help :-) btw this would be an ideal use case for a cronjob

Comment: I need something that's more precise than a minute. Cronjobs don't have that precision unfortunately. :)